# In MS Outlook (365 Apps for Enterprise), how to make strikethrough text?

Tags: text-formatting, microsoft-outlook-365

I am using Microsoft 365 Apps for Enterprise.

When writing an e-mail message from Outlook, there is no option to strike-through text.

[image]

It is still possible to do this by selecting the text, then selecting "Tell me what you want to do" in the menu, and typing "strikethrough", but this is **incredibly** cumbersome.  Is there a faster way?

I've googled for info, but none of the proposed solutions works in my version of Outlook.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do that through the Format dialog. The ribbon has no such option.

- Select the text
- Click "Format Text" in the editing ribbon
- Click the Strikethrough button icon which is an "ab" with
  a line through it. If you don't see this icon, maximize the window.

For more details and screenshots, see the article
[Strike Through Text Easily in any Outlook Email Message](https://www.wikihow.com/Strikethrough-in-Outlook).

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  It is still unclear to me why Microsoft decided to put a crippled version of the Format Text menu in the Message menu.